# While loop on a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small dataframe comprised of two columns, an ORG column and a percentage column. The dataframe is sorted largest to smallest based on the percentage column.

I'd like to create a while loop that adds up the values in the percentage column up until it hits a value of .80 (80%).

So far I've tried:

```
retail_pareto = 0
counter = 0
while retail_pareto < .80:
    retail_pareto += retailerDF[counter]['RETAILER_PCT_OF_CHANGE']
    counter += 1
```

This does not work, both the counter and the counter and retail_pareto value remain at zero with no real error message to help me troubleshoot what I'm doing incorrectly. Ideally, I'd like to end up with a list of the orgs with the largest percentage that together add up to 80%.

I'm not exactly sure what to try next. I've searched these forums, but haven't found anything similar in the forums yet.

Any advice or help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
Example Dataframe:
ORG    PCT
KST    0.582561
ISL    0.290904
BOV    0.254456
BRH    0.10824
GNT    0.0913631
DSH    0.023441
RDM    -0.0119665
JBL    -0.0348893
JBD    -0.071883
WEG    -0.232227



The output that I would expect would be something along the lines of:
ORG    PCT
KST    0.582561
ISL    0.290904
```

Comment: could you show an example of your dataframe and your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I need to be more diligent about including examples in my posts.

Comment: Can you provide the input/output in a more convenient format? Just use `DataFrame.to_records()`, or `.to_csv()`, `to_dict()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df_filtered = df.loc[df['PCT'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum().le(0.80),:]
#if you don't want include where cumsum is greater than 0,80
#df_filtered = df.loc[df['PCT'].cumsum().le(0.80),:] 
print(df_filtered)
   ORG       PCT
0  KST  0.582561
1  ISL  0.290904
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this example to help you?

```py
import pandas as pd

retail_pareto = 0
orgs = []
for i,row in retailerDF.iterrows():
    if retail_pareto <= .80:
        retail_pareto += row['RETAILER_PCT_OF_CHANGE']
        orgs.append(row)
    else:
        break

new_df = pd.DataFrame(orgs)
```

Edit: made it more like your example and added the new DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your loop, take a more *pandasonic* approach.
Start with computing an additional column containing cumulative sum
of *RETAILER_PCT_OF_CHANGE*:

```
df['pct_cum'] = df.RETAILER_PCT_OF_CHANGE.cumsum()
```

For your data, the result is:

```
   ORG  RETAILER_PCT_OF_CHANGE   pct_cum
0  KST                0.582561  0.582561
1  ISL                0.290904  0.873465
2  BOV                0.254456  1.127921
3  BRH                0.108240  1.236161
4  GNT                0.091363  1.327524
5  DSH                0.023441  1.350965
6  RDM               -0.011967  1.338999
7  JBL               -0.034889  1.304109
8  JBD               -0.071883  1.232226
9  WEG               -0.232227  0.999999
```

And now, to print rows which totally include 80 % of change,
ending on the first row above the limit, run:

```
df[df.pct_cum.shift(1).fillna(0) < 0.8]
```

The result, together with the cumulated sum, is:

```
   ORG  RETAILER_PCT_OF_CHANGE   pct_cum
0  KST                0.582561  0.582561
1  ISL                0.290904  0.873465
```